# React Native Defaultsource Image stretch on Android

Tags: android, react-native, image, stretch, distortion

Default Source image is distorted on android release app.
[image]

Actual placeholder image size is 100x100 that is below.
[image]

```
<Image
style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#fc6060' }}
source={ { uri: "https://host/static/08_l.jpg" }}
defaultSource={require('./../../assets/image/default_avtar_placeholder.png')}
resizeMode={"contain"} />
```

> Why image is Distorted?
> How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and by deleting the border styles I got it solved.

Comment: That was my issue as well, very strange

Answer (score 1):

i know its very late .
Recently i also get stuck in this issue , what would i do just wrap Image Component into a View with some style like height and width and defaultSource is working fine according my requirements.